# dynamically add check boxes based upon array value javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code and i would like to add check boxes based upon an array of values:

When i run the code it replaces the check box instead of appending a new one.

**HTML**

```
   <span id="foo">


           </span>
```

**Javascript**

```
function init() {

    var values = ["value1", "Value2", "Value3", "Value4"];

     for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML = '<label><input type="checkbox" value="' + values[i] + '_checkbox">' + values[i] + '</label><br>';

     }

}
```

Comment: Change to: `innerHTML += ...`

Comment: you tried .append() function?

Answer (score 1):

You can try following code,

```
function init() {
    var str =''; //INitial a string
    var values = ["value1", "Value2", "Value3", "Value4"];

     for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
       str +='<label><input type="checkbox" value="' + values[i] + '_checkbox">' + values[i] + '</label><br>'; //Append values in string

     }
document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML = str; //Assign string to element

}
```

Comment: I think it will replace content.

Comment: Ok, Its my mistake :)

Comment: I think @HarshSanghani meant that if #foo already has some content, calling `init()` will replace that content, which your code does. Try calling the function twice (viz. `init(); init();`). His code preserves the contents, however.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by these way :-

```
function init() {
    var str    = document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML;
    var values = ["value1", "Value2", "Value3", "Value4"];

     for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
       str +='<label><input type="checkbox" value="' + values[i] + '_checkbox">' + values[i] + '</label><br>';

     }
document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML = str;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

By this you get only last check box
    function init() {

```
    var values = ["value1", "Value2", "Value3", "Value4"];

     for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML = '<label><input type="checkbox" value="' + values[i] + '_checkbox">' + values[i] + '</label><br>';

     }

}
```

So concatenate your result i.e.

```
for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      text   += '<label><input type="checkbox" value="' + values[i] + '_checkbox">' + values[i] + '</label><br>';

}
document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML = text;
```